# Average Snowfall for Snowy Places?

Tags: meteorology, snow, statistics, severe-weather

I just moved to Wisconsin, so my family is throwing snow statistics at me. But it seems to me that the most meaningful average US snowfall statistic isn't available (or easy to find).

The average snowfall in the US is 28 inches.  But that includes places that never or rarely get snow.  A better stat would limit to places that get some modicum of snow annually.

So, what is the average snowfall for places (perhaps cities) that get at least an inch of snow annually?

Comment: It trally isn't all that meaningful for snowy places, either.  For instance, areas just east & south of the Great Lakes (Buffalo, Oswego, &c), or on the east & west side of the Sierra Nevada, can get a lot more snow than areas some miles inland, even though the periods of actual snowfall are much the same.  The key is the moisture content of the air.

Comment: Rough estimates across the US from each recent year can be found on the [National Snowfall Analysis map](https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/snowfall/index.html?season=2018-2019&date=2019093012&version=3) (change the season, then pick the last date to see the yearly total). [NWS NOWData](https://sercc.com/nowdata.html) offers some more useful local data... select the local NWS office (Milwaukee/Green Bay/Duluth/La Crosse/Minneapolis cover parts of WI)... then pick 1 - desired observation site, 2 - Daily/Monthly normals, then 3 - variable: snowfall (plenty of other interesting data on the site too)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some cities and locations

Average Annual Snowfall for the Following Cities and Locations (in inches)

Asheville, North Carolina: 9.9”

Waynesville, North Carolina: 14.1”

Milwaukee, Wisconsin: 46.9”

Madison, Wisconsin: 50.9”

Syracuse, New York: 123.8”

Buffalo, New York: 94.7”

Smugglers Notch, Vermont: 59.8”

Burlington, Vermont: 59.8”

Mount Washington, New Hampshire: 281.2”

Morristown, New Jersey: 14.1”

New York City, New York: 25.8”

Montpellier, Vermont: 94.2”

Ogden, Utah: 22.1”

Salt Lake City, Utah: 56.2”

Barrow, Alaska: 37.7”

Seattle, Washington: 6.8”

Alta, Utah: 549”

Comment: And another for interest: http://www.thestormking.com/Weather/Sierra_Snowfall/sierra_snowfall.html